# Using Power Automate Workflow - Transfer metaData from List to Library when uploading a document to library

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Is this even possible? I want to create a flow that when a document is uploaded to a library, the workflow verifies if the document name exists in a list in the same site. If yes, then the flow transfers the document metaData from the **list** to the same library in which the document was uploaded. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could refer to the following flow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Rfc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDXXW.png)

Note: The condition in the screenshot is "Name" is equal to "Name", the first Name is one column I create in the lookuplist, the other is the file name.
And in "If yes", the dynamic value "text1" and "text2" are value in lookuplist.

As a result, when I create a file in Document library, the file properties (here are text1 and text2) will be updated:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXIpG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGDvS.png)

Above is updating file properties according to one list, you could use the same logic to add other lists in your site to this flow.